# Iteration over std::vector return same elemement

Tags: c++, stdvector

Following C++ example insert 6 different struct element in vector, but iteration over vector return  last struct element for all iteration.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <sstream>
using namespace std;

typedef struct Nodes {
    char *mgmt;
    char *ops;
} Nodes;


typedef std::vector<Nodes> Devices;

int main() {

    Devices devices;
    size_t count = 6;
    for (size_t i = 0; i < count; ++i)
    {
        std::stringstream mgmt, ops;
        Nodes n = { const_cast<char*>(mgmt.str().c_str()),
                const_cast<char*>(ops.str().c_str())};
        devices.push_back(n);
    }

    for (auto dev : devices) {
        cout << dev.mgmt << endl;
        cout << dev.ops << endl;
    }


return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
mgmt5
ops5
mgmt5
ops5
mgmt5
ops5
mgmt5
ops5
mgmt5
ops5
mgmt5
ops5
```

Expected Output:

```
mgmt0
ops0
mgmt1
ops1
mgmt2
ops2
mgmt3
ops3
mgmt4
ops4
mgmt5
ops5
```

So why there is no expected output ? I was expecting vector will return the 6 different struct element while iteration.

Comment: This pointer `mgmt.str().c_str()` becomes dangling at the end of the line you create it in, because `.str()` returns a temporary object. Why don't you store `std::string`s in the struct, instead of `char *`?

Comment: Please edit your question to provide a [mre]. The posted code doesn't produce the shown output.

Answer (score 1):

You are making mistake here

```
Nodes n = { const_cast<char*>(mgmt.str().c_str()),
                const_cast<char*>(ops.str().c_str())};
```

mgmt  is pointing system input buffer internally, so though you're creating local variables mgmt and ops, they only wrap internal buffer address, and they're unchanged.

[buffers in vector](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6RIyP.png)

Finally all vector elements are pointing internal input buffer and the value is last inputed value with 5 as suffix.

You can allocate string buffer for each Node members and use strcpy.
Or you can wrap in std::string

```
char *str = "hello";
std::string wrapped_str(str);

printf("%08x\n", str);
printf("%08x\n", wrapped_str.c_str());
printf("%s\n", wrapped_str.c_str());
```

output:

```
00400b71
390c9b90
hello
```

when you wrap as std::string, they have different address and it means std::string copied argument char* buffer, instead of pointing internally.

Comment: The `Nodes` type also needs a destructor to avoid memory leaking.

Answer (score 0):

C++ provided powerful `std::string` to facilitate difficulties when operating on characters. In case that you still want C string `char*`, you can use the `strdup` method to allocate memories for it. Doing like this you also need to remember freeing them to avoid leaks. It could be done via Destructor

```
typedef struct Nodes {
    char *mgmt;
    char *ops;
    ~Node() { free(mgmt); free(ops); }
} Nodes;
Nodes n = { strdup(mgmt.str().c_str()),
            strdup(ops.str().c_str())};
```